# is it possible to save/retrieve specific data from webview cache?

Tags: android, webview, browser-cache

i load a web page in a `webview` that contains a form, i want to know if there is a way to save the data that user put in the form in the `webview` cache and auto fill it in his next visit?
this is all i have done for now.

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
      webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
      webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

      webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if it's the right way but, what about running js script on webview to get form input values, navigating DOM tree of html or using selector with  id ?

once you got them you can store them in your app and for repopulate, before loading the page in webview, you manipulate html (if you could) or you use another js script to set the values

i'm not sure but i thing cache is only for cachable values (images, css...) not for input